# Problem with Eset and libssl

Tags: openssl, 22.04

I tried to find something in google, but this is I think too new problem:

After I tried to install esset:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     138962674 lut 10 17:19  eea-9.0.5.0-ubuntu18.x86_64.deb
```

Using this command (as is mentioned in doc)

```
dpkg -i eea-9.0.5.0-ubuntu18.x86_64.deb
```

I get error like this:

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX/Downloads# dpkg -i eea-9.0.5.0-ubuntu18.x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 167529 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack eea-9.0.5.0-ubuntu18.x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking eea (9.0.5.0) over (9.0.5.0) ...
Setting up eea (9.0.5.0) ...
/opt/eset/eea/bin/upd: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ESET Endpoint Antivirus error: Module compilation failed.
/opt/eset/eea/lib/cfg: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: 22.04 uses OpenSSL 3.0 which I don't believe provides the 1.1 libraries.  It's also very likely that Eset has not yet done their updates to support latest OpenSSL.  I would contact ESET about this since it's their proprietary code.

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas Ward is right about the 1.1 libraries being needed. I was able to get around this by first uninstalling ESET eea, then copying the needed libssl.so.1.1 and libcrypto.so.1.1 libraries from the already installed snap runtime to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, and reinstalling.

```
cp /snap/core20/1434/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

cp /snap/core20/1434/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Sparks, thanks this tipp helps. i used file from current directory, cause 1434 not there. works fine! clever :-)

process, after uninstall:

```
sudo cp /snap/core20/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo cp /snap/core20/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo dpkg -i eea-9.0.5.0-ubuntu18.x86_64.deb
```

https://help.eset.com/eeau/9/de-DE/?activate_eeau.html

Glad to get this done on ubuntu 22.04